# Telerik Reporting VS Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, business-intelligence, telerik-reporting

I'm not getting any relevant result when Googling this `Telerik Reporting VS Tableau`, may be because these two are completely different in what they do. But they both can be used to create reports, then why no one is comparing them? I don't know....

The only thing which I'm not sure about is whether Telerik Reporting do BI stuff or not, which Tableau seems to be a popular tool for. Can someone please tell:

- Does Telerik Reporting support BI like Tableau does? I found an [old blog](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/telerik-reporting-gets-closer-to-becoming-a-true-business-intelligence-bi-solution) from 2009, but nothing new about this topic.
- If no, then what BI (Business Intelligence) features which Telerik Reporting    does not support?
- If yes, then which one will be a better choice Telerik Reporting or Tableau?

Comment: Last time I was involved with Telerik it was just a third party web control company. Looking at their site now, it seems like it may have more features but it's unlikely that they've caught up with Tableau. For example I doubt that Telerik offers a SaaS cloud solution. Also Telerik is not in the Gartner magic quadrant. Those are my observations from 5 minutes googling. TBH I'm going to request to close this as it is a shopping list / opinion question.

Comment: Snooping on your profile, it would seem you have plenty of experience with Telerik so I suggest you go do some reading / research / videos on Tableau.

Comment: like you said the two solutions server two different purposes. Telerik (I only used the very early version) is more of a white label solution for developers to integrate with other solutions, whereas Tableau (which I use daily now) is more of a standalone data visualization tool for power users and end users (For advanced report and dashboard, having someone with tech background to build the report, but the UI is intuitive enough that it is not often necessary)